# java.lang.Object android.support.v4.app.i.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' in 2g network

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

It works fine in **4G** network and **3G** network. but it working sometimes in 2G network and randomly I am getting crashing. How to overcome from this issue. help me out.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.jamhub.barbeque, PID: 17623 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Objectandroid.support.v4.app.i.getSystemService(java.lang.String)'
on a null object reference                                                       
    at com.jamhub.barbeque.b.b.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.jamhub.barbeque.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jamhub.barbeque.b.b$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.jamhub.barbeque.b.b$b.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: share your code.

Comment: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v4.app.p.isFinishing()' on a null object reference
       at com.jamhub.barbeque.MainFragments.HomeFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at com.android.volley.Request.getTrafficStatsTag(Unknown Source)
       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)

Comment: @HemantParmar ,i dont know y.its crashing

Comment: try to put (getActivity()!=null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) in all the places of your HomeFragment

Comment: @Lucky where i have to put.   
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

Comment: I think you have created an method to check internet connectivity, so before calling this method of internet connectivity check you have to also check if your getActivity() context is null or not, and if you can show some more of your code that would be great to understand problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed that issue by adding condition like activity not equal to null.
if((getActivity()!=null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) {
--your code--
}

Comment: You just masked the real problem. Do you understand *why* it's happening?

Comment: @EugenPechanec,no,if you know,please explain me,it will helpful for everyone.

Comment: You activity is destroyed and recreated when you rotate screen, leave app, sometimes lock phone. The task continues running but the result is thrown away. Maybe even the same task is running again. Depends on your code. Read [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e) and [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/lifecycle-aware-data-loading-with-android-architecture-components-f95484159de4).

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thank you for your technical explanation towards my query.